# What do you call the thing when three or more people in a line are whooping in a circle?

Tags: durarara

[image]

Was watching the newest Episode of Bochi the Rock and Saw it again, it's haunted me for years, but what is that called? the little spinny Hype Dance, Gif Above From Durarara!! because I couldn't figure out the term to find the Bochi one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not really a name for it.

It is from a song [Choo Choo Train](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choo_Choo_TRAIN) by a group named ZOO (In the article, it uses Choo Choo train Dance). It was covered by another dancer-singer group [Exile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exile_(Japanese_band)). Mainly the dance/movement is known because of this cover, so in Japan, most people recognize it as 'that thing of Exile'.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AL0TE79SbP4) is the original Zoo's performance, where the movement is in the opposite direction. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owWPR-5sKeM) (Exile version) is the same as the one you posted.